# For loop and while loop comparison

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop

So I did the next exercise, just with `while` loop:

> Write a program that prompts the user for two integers.
> Print each number in the range specified by those two integers.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Write two numbers: " << std::endl;
    int v1 = 0, v2 = 0;
    std::cin >> v1 >> v2;
    std::cout << "The numbers between " << v1 << " and " << v2 << " are: " << std::endl;

    while (v2 < v1 && ++v2 < v1)
    {
        std::cout << v2 << std::endl;
    }

    while (v1 < v2 && ++v1 < v2)
    {
        std::cout << v1 << std::endl;
    }

}
```

Now I have to do it with the `for` loop, which I did like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Write two numbers: " << std::endl;
    int a, b;
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    std::cout << "The numbers between " << a << " and " << b << " are: " << std::endl;

    for (; a < b && ++a < b; a)
    {
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
    }
    
    for (; b < a && ++b < a; b)
    {
        std::cout << b << std::endl;
    }
}
```

It looks almost the same, but it works.

**My questions is: I'm I missing something about the `for` loop, could I do it simpler?**

PD: Just `for` loop, I'm not in the `If` chapter yet, I want to go step by step on the "C++ Primer 5th edition".

Comment: The question is unclear. What is the problem?

Comment: There is no problem, just asking if there is a way I can do it simpler with the for loop, I'm asking this because both, while and for look very similar.

Comment: The third expressions in the for loop as that for (; a < b && ++a < b; a) us redundant. You could write  for (; a < b && ++a < b; )

Comment: `for (; a < b && ++a < b; a)` this is a very strange pattern, maybe you rather want want this: `for (; a < b; a++)`?

Comment: Consider [codereview.se] for working code that you'd like reviewed

Comment: Thanks for the code review link!

Comment: All three parts of the `for` loop are optional, so if you don't need the "increment" part you can just skip it like you do for the initialization part, like `for (; a < b && ++a < b; )`

Answer (score 1):

`for` is specified in terms of `while`, you aren't missing anything.

> for (*init-statement* *condition*<sub>opt</sub>;
> *iteration-expression*<sub>opt</sub>) *statement*
>
> produces code equivalent to:
>
> { *init-statement* while (*condition*) { *statement*
> *iteration-expression*; } }
>
> Except that
>
> 1. Names declared by the *init-statement* (if *init-statement* is a declaration) and names declared by *condition* (if *condition* is a
>    declaration) are in the same scope (which is also the scope of
>    *statement*).
> 2. `continue` in the *statement* will execute *iteration-expression*
> 3. Empty *condition* is equivalent to `while(true)`

[from cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for)

You don't need anything in *iteration-expression* `for(;;)` is equivalent to `while(true)`

it would be more normal to increment in the *iteration-expression*, and not repeat almost the same test.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Write two numbers: " << std::endl;
    int a, b;
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    std::cout << "The numbers between " << a << " and " << b << " are: " << std::endl;

    for (; a < b; ++a)
    {
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
    }
    
    for (; b < a; ++b)
    {
        std::cout << b << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The for loop is intended to loop between two numbers. The use of your for loops unreadable for it's intentions. Take a look at this

```
int end = 10;
for (int begin = 0; begin < end; ++begin){/*do something*/}
```

This is the standard structure of a for loop. Now for your example you will get the following

```
#include <algorithm>
if (a > b) std::swap(a, b);
for (int begin = a; begin <= b; ++begin){
    std::cout << begin << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: ops loop is not "wrong". And "no one does that" isnt right either. Commonly the increment is done in the increment expression but not necessarily

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I have edited my answer. But yes in this case no one does that. passing the condition from the while in the for loop and it works too, but no one does that.

Comment: why do you insist that no one does it? It is simple to disproove, i just did it: https://godbolt.org/z/P57Mnfh3q. Seriously, ommitting the increment expression is not too uncommon.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I'm not claiming no one omits the increment. Since it's often necessary when erasing from a vector in a loop. I'm saying no one only keeps the boolean expression. Since you would just have a botched while loop.

Comment: that isnt true either. If you already have the counter available then it is not uncommon to have only the condition : https://godbolt.org/z/xYcrcMba6

Answer (score 0):

There is no need on using something like `a < b && ++a < b` since `a < b` is contained in `++a < b` condition. So just using `++a < b` you will get the same results.

Now about the `for` you should write it like this just to make your code a bit clear:

```
for (; a < b; ++a)
{
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

I am not using the initialization sentence as you have already initialized your variables, however I encorage you to initialize `a` in the `for` sentence

In general terms, the for is divided in three sections:

```
for (<initialization sentence>; <condition sentence>; <post-execution sentence>)
```

The initialization only runs when the for sentence is reached, and the loop is running while the condition is met. The post-execution it is normally used to increase or change state of the variables involved in the condition criteria. The only constraint you have is that condition must be a boolean sentence.

None of those sections should be an assigment, a common comparison or a variable increment. You could use whatever fits your requirements and met the for constraints.

To sum up, a for sentence is a 'wrapped' structure of a while. You could get the same results with both. The difference is on a cleaner image of your code and a better understanding of the algorithms.

Comment: The `a < b && ++a < b` guards against the case where `b` is less than `a` to begin with; the code should fall through to the second loop without modifying `a`. Granted, that's not an obvious way of doing that, but you can't just ignore that possibility.

Comment: The `for` loop in this answer displays the initial value of `a`, but the original code doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question is somewhat confusing, because it tries to do several things at once. I'd separate them.

Instead of writing two loops, I'd just change the limits:
if (v2 < v1)
std::swap(v2, v1);

Now it's easy:

```
while (++v1 < v2)
    std::cout << v1 << '\n';
```

Same thing for the `for` loop. After adjusting the limits, just do it:

```
for ( ; ++a < b; )
    std::cout << a << '\n';
```